# How to get selected language from google translate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using google translate for translating the web content.But as we know that it creates the div and classes itself, So i am unable to get selected language from drop down of google translate. I surf so many sites and so many questions but i did not find any appropriate answer.I want a solution that should not depends on cookies, And how I can call google translate every time with  default language get from database for particular users.. My website is in english by default but i want that it should open in other language if other user choose their default language. I will be so thankful for a good solutions.I am using this normal code with 4 languages

```js
<div id="google_translate_element" style="margin:10px 0 0;"> </div><div id="language"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function initializeGoogleTranslateElement() {
 new google.translate.TranslateElement({
  layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
  includedLanguages: "zh-CN,en,ja,ko"
 }, "google_translate_element");
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 <div id="google_translate_element"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: "hi,en" }, 'google_translate_element');
        }
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution use below code to select your default language, you can load the default language from the database:

```
<div id="google_translate_element" style="float:left;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'ja', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,includedLanguages: "zh-CN,en,ja,ko"
    }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I already use it. But in chrome it showing error of file not found when it try to execute "//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" and in firefox its not showing any error but not working too.

Comment: I find the solution to detect the selected language, but now how i can execute that language by default

Comment: I have tried this code in jsFiddel and it is working fine at both the browsers. I think in your code some other JS issue is causing this error.

Comment: hello bro.. sorry i lost my network yesterday.. btw can you give me that fiddle link ? for me that pageLanguage not working. and when i uploaded the complete script on the server, whole customization of dropdown box turn to default layout and it showing two dropdown for choosing language.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Google translate adds an attribute "lang" on  tag.

```
<html lang="en"></html>
```

Use the code below to get the selected language code -
`document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('lang')`

Comment: Still working the same way in 2024.  Best answer as far as I'm concerned.